# How can I get a larger quantity of google play id

Tags: google-identity

How can I get a larger quantity of google play id 
I have a site for an android applications but I need to get the largest amount of id google 
So you can share them on your site

Comment: What do you mean, `largest amount of id google`?

Comment: Yes from App ID , So applications can be added to your site via one software